# Extending Qt plugin

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qml

I have a question about c++ plugins in Qt5 with QML UI.

Lets say we have application A and application B. Both using plugin C which is written in c++ to draw some QQuickItems in qml.

Both application working fine. Now I have to extend the plugin with some more options (nothing to draw, but based on the data already available in plugin C) which - and thats the problem - should be only available in application B.

Why? The extra options needing some includes from other libraries which should be not added to application A. So application A should run with the basic plugin and application should run with the extended plugin.

My question is what is the best/common way to achieve this?

I just thought about it a little bit and got some (in my opion not very good) solutions/ideas:

1. Writing a plugin D which can do the extended options. So application A can run with plugin C and application runs with plugins C and D. The disadvantage is that the 2 plugins needs to communicate heavily (plugin D needs the data of C) via qml. I think thats not very nice, may there be a better way to do the data transfer between two plugins?
2. Writing 2 plugins where plugin C is the basic one and plugin D has the content of plugin C plus the extended options. Well that should of course work but I will have to maintenance the code twice. That's definitely not nice.
3. I thought about some conditional includes to just include the extended options if corresponding flags are set. I do not have any experience with that. But could this be possible?

Comment: Look at [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, no need to reinvent the wheel, just use what has been proven by time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you to proceed is your third option. You can add a init function to your plugin.

```
class PluginC : public plugininterface {

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "plugininterface")
    Q_INTERFACES(plugininterface)

public:
    /* Init the plugin */
    void init( bool extended );

    ...
    ...
    ...

private:
    bool m_extended;
};
```

Rest of the plugin can be built just as usual, with all the features you want. In your application A, you can init your plugin with extended = false, and application B, you can init your plugin with extended = true